# Infinite loop in shouldOverrideUrlLoading

Tags: android

This piece of code creates an infinite loop when I try to display a PDF file, how can I avoid that?

Thanks.

```
mWebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
         @Override
         public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             String hello = Uri.parse(url).getHost();
             if (url.endsWith(".pdf")){
                 System.out.println("pdf: " + url);
                 view.loadUrl("http://docs.google.com/gview?embedded=true&url=" + url);
                 return true;
             } else {
                System.out.println("no pdf: " + url);
                view.loadUrl(url);

             }
             return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: don't call webview.loadurl in this method

Comment: But then how can I display pdf files?

Comment: The webviewclient is not responsible for loading them, only for delegating if the webview should respond to a load call or not. That is why you're override a boolean method in the first place. Call loadurl in your activity.

Answer (score 2):

Your `else` should be:

```
} else {
  System.out.println("no pdf: " + url);
}
```

Your loop will occur because everytime he will do a `loadUrl-> shouldOverrideUrlLoading -> loadUrl`

If you don't change the url, just return false.

Comment: Are you sure you called setWebViewClient only once?